# How to remove numbers after a comma?

Tags: javascript, string, number-formatting

I have strings like this: `300.123,25` and after the comma I want to have always one digit.

Expected result: `300.123,2`

Another issue would be to auto concatenate `,0` if the string does not have a comma

```
300.123  ->  300.123,0
```

With the value from the input:

```
value = value.toString().replace(/[^0-9\,]/g, "")
value = value.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".")
```

I removed letters and other symbols. I've tried to check if I a have digits after comma with this: '(,\d)\d*$'. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you share the code for which you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const value = `300.123,25`;
const parts = value.split(",");
const result = `${parts[0]},${parts[1] ? (parts[1][0] || "0") : "0"}`;
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Every time I change the input, my cursor is placed at the end of the string. Can you tell me why?

Comment: This has nothing to to with the Question above. 
But: this depends on how you render the value in the input. How do you render the HTML input?

Comment: With a react hook. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Okay in react you need to have a state as your input value. Do you use `useState` for your input value?

Comment: `300.123` => `split(",").length === 1` => `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const toFixed = (sv) => sv.replace(/(?<=\.).+/, (x) => Number.parseFloat(x.replace(',', '.')).toFixed(1).replace('.', ','))
console.log(
  toFixed('300.123,25'),
  toFixed('300.123')
)
```